# Visual Studio 2012 changes IIS application directory without asking

Tags: visual-studio, iis

If you have a solution with web applications configured with IIS, Visual Studio will set up the virtual directories and point them to your code.  If you have multiple branches for that solution, there will be different directories for the same IIS applications.  If you open up a solution from a branch different from the one the IIS applications are currently pointed to, VS2010 would warn you and then ask if you want to change the directories.  VS 2012 doesn't warn you, it just changes the directories with out asking.

Is there any way to get that warning back?  Is there a way to set VS2012 to not change the directories or a tool to do it manually?

Quite often I am working in one branch but I want to look at the code in another branch.  If I open that branch up in VS2012, it changes the directories in IIS and now the applications are pointed at the wrong code.  2010 would ask me so I could tell it 'no' if I didn't want it to change directories.

Thanks,
Matthew