# Opening projects changes iis settings

Tags: visual-studio, iis

I have this problem, when developing I use git and often clone to a new folder to fix smaller bugs. The problem is that as soon as I open my project Visual Studio changes the IIS settings to point to the new folder. Is there some way of preventing this from happening? Like hold down ctrl when opening the project or something?

Comment: This is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/3093433/90033

Comment: And even more to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646726/visual-studio-2012-changes-iis-application-directory-without-asking?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If you open your project settings, and then go to the Web tab, changing the Servers section to `External Host` should fix this.

Comment: Ok I know about this one, but it would affect other users in my team too I guess...

Comment: If you use versions below VS2013, you should be able to uncheck the `Apply server settings to all users (store in project file)` setting. Unfortunately, in VS2013, this is no longer present and `SaveServerSettingsInUserFile ` is not respected either: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800003/the-apply-server-settings-to-all-users-store-in-project-file-option-is-missing-in-vs2013.